# Selecionar colunas dinamicamente com Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma action numa API que deve retornar um modelo, porém os campos que devem ser retornados são informados na requisição. Consigo fazer uma consulta com o pacote System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, mas a performance é bem ruim. Qual outra alternativa posso usar? Estou usando .Net 4.5

Exemplo da consulta:

```
var contexto = new SgdbContext();

//Esse select só é possivel por causa do pacote
foreach(dynamic profissional in contexto.Profissional.Select("new (Id, Nome)"))
{
    var conteudo = $"{profissional.Id} - {profissional.Nome}";
}
```

Comment: Mostre o que você já tem de código.

Comment: A consulta que fiz é um select básico trazendo 2 colunas (id e nome por exemplo), mas só nesse teste da para perceber a lentidão. De forma alguma vou usar esse código.

Comment: Talvez você precise procurar por [OData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525392(v=vs.103).aspx). Provavelmente, hoje em dia já exista algo melhor, ou uma versão melhorada, mas acho que esse é o caminho.

Comment: Consegui uma solução com `dynamic` à noite eu posto

Comment: Poste a sua action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou seguir a dica do usuário "LINQ", valeu cara. O [OData](https://www.odata.org) é a melhor opção no meu caso. Estou implementando uma api restful, seguindo todas as boas práticas, então essa é a melhor opção. Porque ao criar um controller odata na api, com as actions padrões que o Visual Studio cria, já consigo ter uma action que faz justamente o que preciso, receber uma requisição com os campos desejados e retornar esses campos no json, automático, não preciso fazer nada. E a performance é tão boa quanto uma query linq normal.

Um [link](https://rodolfofadino.com.br/asp-net-core-e-odata-f0100c41c2a4) de um artigo de implementação do OData em .Net Core.

Exemplo de url odata:

> http://localhost:51971/odata/Profissional?$select=Id,Nome

Exemplo da action:

```
//Essa action responde a url acima
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Profissional> GetProfissional()
{
    return db.Profissional;
}
```

Comment: Showzera. Quando tiver uma implementação básica, poste o o código nessa resposta.

Comment: Feito. Show de bola.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o tipo `dynamic`, a classe `ExpandoObject` que suporta `IDictionary<string, object>` para adicionar as propriedades em tempo execução... Você pode começar a sua implementação com o exemplo abaixo.

```
public class PessoasController : ApiController
{      
    public IEnumerable<object> Get(string exibir = "")
    {
        //Consulta ao repositório, simulada.
        var lista = new List<PessoaViewModel>
        {
            new PessoaViewModel{ Id = 1, Nome="Nome 1", Sobrenome = "Sobrenome 1" },
            new PessoaViewModel{ Id = 2, Nome="Nome 2", Sobrenome = "Sobrenome 2" },
            new PessoaViewModel{ Id = 3, Nome="Nome 3", Sobrenome = "Sobrenome 3" }
        };


        //faz o split pelo separador 
        var queryFilter = exibir.Split(',');

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exibir) && queryFilter.Length <= 0)
        {
            return lista;
        }
        else{
            // Utilizando reflection retorna apenas as propriedades informadas no filtro,
            // que existem no objeto comparação.
            var propriedades = typeof(PessoaViewModel)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(x => queryFilter.Select(q => q.ToLower()).Contains(x.Name.ToLower()))
                .ToList();

            // Se as propriedades de filtro não batem com o modelo, retorna o objeto inteiro
            if (propriedades.Count() == 0)
                return lista;

            // Aqui é a onde a mágica acontece, utilizando o ExpandoObject,
            // criamos um dicionário armazenando o nome e valor daquelas 
            // propriedades que existem, de fato, na classe.
            var output = lista.Select(registro =>
            {
                dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
                var temp = x as IDictionary<string, object>;

                foreach (var prop in propriedades)
                    temp.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(registro));

                return x;
            });

            return output;
        }          

    }

}
```

**Demonstração:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referência:**

[Building C# objects dynamically - O'Reilly Media](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-c-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Bacana, mas o ideal é que o EF já fizesse isso (ridiculo que até a versão 6 não tenha nada do tipo). Tentei usar o método SqlQuery<Model> do contexto, mas também não deixa trazer somente os campos que preciso (dinamicamente)

Comment: Hmm, você quer fazer o select dinâmico no EF tbm, pensei que a sua questão era mais relacionada o retorno do valor na api, então nesse caso a tag `asp.net-web-api` é irrelevante, correto?

Comment: Lembrando que reflection é **extremamente lento**.